# Drupal 7 or 8 for bilingual site

Tags: i18n-l10n

I am working on a large project for a bilingual site. I would like to move their site from Wordpress to Drupal and see the multilingual capabilities of Drupal 8. However, the site won't be ready to build until late summer of 2015. Would it be a good idea to build on Drupal 8 or because of lag of modules and such, use Drupal 7. As I'm not using Drupal 7 now and don't need to worry about upgrading modules, I think it would be ok to go right into 8. I would like some feedback as to the best route.

Comment: It depends on too many factors. For example module lag - it's impact depends solely on which modules you will need, and you did not provide this info. And so on. Your reasoning seems fine, but I don't think this can have *reliable answer*.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal 8 is great, and has a lot of improvements related to multi language sites. But Drupal 8 isn't ready yet, and it "will be ready when it's ready" (that's what some experienced Drupal-ers say, and I do fully understand that).

Also, after Drupal 8 is released (I've heard dates like somewhere in 2016 only, and it wouldn't surprise me), there are still all the contributed modules that will not be upgraded yet to Drupal 8. Today there are still Drupal 6 modules waiting for their Drupal 7 upgrade) ...

For all these reasons, I will continue to go for Drupal 7 for quite a while (probably at least the rest of 2015). Because of its maturity, and because I would not want to depend on a Drupal 8 release of either core, or any of the contributed modules that I "must have".

There is also that great presentation from David Reid about all those [amazing contributed modules in Drupal 7, which are like backports of new Drupal 8 features](https://amsterdam2014.drupal.org/session/future-proof-your-drupal-7-site.html).