# Should I go for Drupal7 or Drupal8?

Tags: nodes

I am currently developing my website. It is in initial stage. I got pretty good hand on Drupal7. But as Drupal8 is going to release in few days should I shift to drupal8 from now itself as my development is in very initial stage Or should I stick to Drupal7?

Comment: It comes down to what functionality you need. Simply put, for an advanced site go with D7, for a more simple site D8 might work out.

Comment: This question seems like a variation of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/150659 ... not sure if it is an exact duplicate though ...

Comment: Hi all, I do not know whether this kind of question has been asked previously or not. But as I was developing my website and got a news of Drupal8 so naturally this question arises that whether person should work with 7 or go for 8. Hence as I am totally new to drupal and web development, arising such questions is completely genuine. Hence person Naturally end-up at "Drupal Answers" to get view from more Experienced People so that person can go ahead with its work. Hence, I believe this is not just OPINION based question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drupal 8 is a better platform , it has a better structure , more features in core , it is based on symphony2 and so the module development is different from what you knew in drupal 7. template engine also is changed to twig so again you have to change your point of view about how used to theme before .

Another thing must be mentioned before making your decision is that there are too many module for drupal 7 and you can find a module for almost any job but cause drupal 8 is new , many modules are not still developed for this version.

All in all I should suggest you that it is a good idea to migrate to drupal 8 but if you have a deadline for your project this may not be a good decision to start it with drupal 8 ,cause it will take some times to be adopted.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After reading, may be I should stick to drupal7 as of now. As I found all modules what is need for my website of drupal7 version and I need website very soon. May be I should migrate to it after sometime.